# Non useful tkinter window appears in spyder

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder

Question 1: I have a non useful window that appears when using tkinter in spyder.
Any solution for this issue ?

[image]

Question 2: Why there is a warning message on 'from tkinter import *' ?

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
from tkinter import messagebox

box = Tk()

name =  askstring('Name','What is your name?')
messagebox.showinfo('Hello!','Hi, {}'.format(name))

box.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

The "non useful" window is simply `box`.
`messagebox` will open a new window. So you can just remove `box` if you don't intend to use it further.

It's usually not recommended to import everything from a module because it could cause name conflicts with other modules or built-in function:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring

name = askstring('Name','What is your name?')
tk.messagebox.showinfo('Hello!','Hi, {}'.format(name))
```

Comment: `askstring()` will raise exception if no root window is created.

Comment: @acw1668 what do you mean? The above code doesn't seem to raise any exception...?

Comment: It raises `RuntimeError: Too early to create dialog window: no default root window` when I run the code in my Windows 7 with Python 3.8.15.

Comment: @acw1668  I don't get an exception either.. using windows 11 and python 3.10

Comment: interesting, they must have changed that somewhere along the line. Can confirm with python 3.11. @acw1668

Comment: Yes it works fine in my Windows 10 with Python 3.10.8.

Comment: right! the change was introduced on the 25th of December 2020: https://github.com/python/cpython/commits/3.11/Lib/tkinter/simpledialog.py

Comment: i got this "RuntimeError: Too early to create dialog window: no default root window" with windows 10 and python 3.11

Comment: @user20580476 should be available in python 3.10 https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/86887 As a workaround you can look into my answer, if you didn't get around.

Answer (score 1):

The additional window is the instance of `Tk` most often named **root** cause every other window or widget is a child of the root window. You will need it to initiate your `messagebox` but if you don't want to look at it you have several choices.
My personal recommendation is to us `overrideredirect` which will discard it from the *taskbar* and use `withdraw` to actually hide it in the screen/monitor. But you may prefer `wm_attributes('-alpha', 0)` over it to make it opaque/transparent.

Avoiding *wildcard* imports is recommanded because of name clashes/collisions. For example tkinter has a `PhotoImage` class, so does `pillow`. If you have wildcard imports on both, on PhotoImage will overwrite the other in the global namespace.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
from tkinter import messagebox

box = tk.Tk()
box.overrideredirect(True)
box.withdraw()

name =  askstring('Name','What is your name?') #blocks the code block
messagebox.showinfo('Hello!','Hi, {}'.format(name)) #shows message
box.after(5000, box.destroy) #destroy root window after 5 seconds
box.mainloop()#blocks until root is destroyed
```

Comment: You have no way to close the hidden root window after closing the message box.  So it is better not calling `box.mainloop()`.

Comment: @acw1668 True, but not sure if it works on every IDE's. I will edit it to include a timer that destroys the root window. OP, didn't clarified how this is intended. Comments will guide OP for the next steps.

Answer (score -1):

For the first question answer is that you don't need to create `box` because function `askstring` create frame on it's own. So if the whole program is just to ask for the name and to greet user, you are perfectly fine with just this piece of code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
from tkinter import messagebox

name =  askstring('Name','What is your name?')
messagebox.showinfo('Hello!','Hi, {}'.format(name))
```

And for the second question you need to post what warning you get.

Comment: `askstring()` will raise exception if no root window is created.

Comment: I don't get any exception

Comment: i confirm, i got "RuntimeError: Too early to create dialog window: no default root window"

Comment: maybe in some older versions of python. https://github.com/python/cpython/commits/3.11/Lib/tkinter/simpledialog.py